# in long term options on equities, what is the greek used for security lending rate, and what formula do you use?

Tags: greeks, pricing-formulae

in long term options on equities, what is the greek used for for security lending rate, and what formula do you use?

would it often move contrary to moves in risk free (ois) and so in practice is it best to hedge seperately from general ois level...